# VueJs and ChartJs - Chart is responsive in width, but not height?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I've tried almost everything but can't get the height of my chart to be responsive.

The width works perfectly, it is responsive and adjusts accordingly, but for some reason the height stays locked at 400px?

In my main Vue app I call my component (passing in the chart data):

`<ProjectedCumulativeSavings :datacollection="projectData.projectedCumulativeSavings" />`

The component ProjectedCumulativeSavings.vue code is:

```
<template>
    <div class="chart-container" >
        <bar-chart
            :chart-data="datacollection"
            :options="options"
            chart-id="projectedCumulativeSavings"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import BarChart from '../mixins/BarChart.js'

export default {
    components: {
        BarChart
    },
    props: {
        datacollection: ''
    },
    data() {
        return {
            options: {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Projected Cumulative Savings',
                    fontSize: 18
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            // Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                            callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                return 'R' + value.toLocaleString('en')
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
    },
    computed: {
    }
}
</script>

<style >
.chart-container {
    min-width: 375px;
    max-width: 1024px;
    /* margin: 30px; */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40vw;
}
</style>
```

BarChart.js code is:

```
import { Bar, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins

export default {
    extends: Bar,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    props: ['options'],
    mounted() {
        // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
        // If you want to pass options please create a local options object

        this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    },
    watch: {
        chartData() {
            this.$data._chart.update()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem and found this.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html#important-note

Try this

```
    <bar-chart
        :chart-data="datacollection"
        :options="options"
        :styles="myStyles"  <-- add this
        chart-id="projectedCumulativeSavings"
    />
```

And

```
    computed: {
        myStyles() {
          return {
            height: '20vh',   <-- this makes your chart responsive
            position: 'relative',
          };
    },
```

Comment: Hi - I ended up taking my charts back to basics to get it working, but thank you for this none the less. I can see how this will work but won't be able to confirm unfortunately. Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that has worked for me is setting the height and width on the component as such:

```
<BarChart
   :chart-data="chart2Data"
   :options="chart2Options"
   :key="chart2Trigger"
   :height="2"
   :width="4"
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Vue3 and vue-chartjs, and encounted the same problem.
My solution is setting options `{ response : false }`, and then setting style object with computed.

like this, setting computed style first:

```
const chartStyle = computed(() => {
  return {
    height: '20vh',
    width: '100%',
    position: 'relative',
  }
})
```

and then add into `<Bar>` style prop

```
<Bar
  :style="chartStyle"
/>
```

Wish the solution is helpful.